# heroku knex migration/seed error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host ssl false

Tags: heroku, migration, seed, knex.js

Trying to use the Heroku console to run knex migration and seeds. Everything works in the development environment but it doesn't in Heroku. I get an SSL error and I don't know how to solve it without paying for a higher database tier.

Answer (score 1):

Because node-Postgres enables SSL validation by default while free Heroku hosting doesn’t provide it automatically, you need to turn it off. disable SSL in Heroku:
[image]

CLI solution:

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify --app <app name>
```

Sources:

https://dpletzke.medium.com/configuring-free-heroku-node-postgresql-hosting-with-knex-b0e97a05c6af

https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with:

```
{
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    },
  },
}
```